# Clear Post data after event delete in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar. When I click an event a modal opens where you can choose to delete the event.

When I click delete, the event is deleted and a php-script is launched which will create a file on ftp to sync with another program. This works fine.
When I click delete on the next event. The php script creates two files. (the first one again and a new one.

When I click delete on the third event, The php script creates 3... and so on.
If I refresh the page between deleting two events there is no problem.

I use `$id = $_POST['id'];` to get the id from the event in the php script.

This is the code I use in fullcalendar:

```
eventClick:  function(event, delta) {
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(   'Start: ' + moment(event.start).format('h:mm') + '</br>' +
                                        'Stop: ' + moment(event.stop).format('h:mm') + '</br></br>' +
                                        'Locatie: ' + event.location + '</br></br>' +
                                        'Info: </br>' + event.description + '</br></br>' +
                                        '<b>Debug info:</b> </br>' +
                                        '           Event id :' + event.id +'</br>' +
                                        '           Resource id :' + event.resourceId +'</br>' +
                                        '           Last modified :' + moment(event.datelastmodified).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss')
                                    );
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                $("#deleteEventBtn").click(function() { 
                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id); //external event, therefore using event._id
                                                        $.ajax({
                                                                url: 'delete_events.php',
                                                                data: '&id='+ event.id ,
                                                                type: "POST",
                                                                success: function(json) {   //refresh calendar on success
                                                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                                            //alert("Updated Successfully");
                                                                                        },
                                                                error: function(json)   {   //refresh calendar on error
                                                                                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                                        },
                                                                statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "delete_events.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                                });
                                                    });
                $('#DeleteEventModal').modal();
        },
```

I discoverd another problem. When I click on an event the modal opens. When I click "close" to close the modal en click on the next event and choose to "delete" both events are erased.

**EDIT:**
I think I need some code like this one:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#DeleteEventModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#DeleteEventModal .modal-body').html('');
});})
</script>
```

This code deletes the html-body, I need for it to clear the event id.
Everytime I click an event the `event.id` is added to the cache(?). When I click delete. Every event with cached event.id is deleted instead of only the last event clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. Every time an event is clicked in the calendar a new handler was bound to the #deleteEventBtn. Thus when I clicked "delete", multiple handlers were executed.

Working code:

```
eventRender:  function(event, element) {
                element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
                element.click(function() {
                    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                    $('#modalBody').html(   'Start: ' + moment(event.start).format('h:mm') + '</br>' +
                                            'Stop: ' + moment(event.stop).format('h:mm') + '</br></br>' +
                                            'Locatie: ' + event.location + '</br></br>' +
                                            'Info: </br>' + event.description + '</br></br>' +
                                            '<b>Debug info:</b> </br>' +
                                            '           Event id :' + event.id +'</br>' +
                                            '           Resource id :' + event.resourceId +'</br>' +
                                            '           Last modified :' + moment(event.datelastmodified).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss')
                                        );
                    $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                    $("#deleteEventBtn").off('click').on('click', function(e) {
                                                            //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id); //external event, therefore using event._id
                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                    url: 'delete_events.php',
                                                                    data: '&id='+ event.id ,
                                                                    type: "POST",
                                                                    success: function(json) {   //refresh calendar on success
                                                                                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                                                //alert("Updated Successfully");
                                                                                            },
                                                                    error: function(json)   {   //refresh calendar on error
                                                                                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                                                                            },
                                                                    statusCode: {404: function() {alert( "delete_events.php niet gevonden. De wijziging wordt niet opgeslagen." )}},
                                                                    });
                    });
                    $('#DeleteEventModal').modal();
                });
        },
```